# How do reconnecting nodes in a database synchronize with majority cluster?

Tags: database, distributed-transactions, distributed-system

Consider a database with a total of 5 copies over 5 machines. A write to the database involves something like two phase commit among all 5 machines to maintain consistency.

Suppose one machine goes down. Then writes to the database can still occur as running two phase commit over the other 4 nodes since that is still a majority.

But when the down machine comes back up and reconnects how does it synchronize and rejoin the cluster?

The rejoining machine needs to get the commit log entries it does not have. Presumably it runs some kind of consensus algorithm amongst all 5 machines to achieve agreement on the next log entry it is missing. And it keeps doing this until it catches up on missing commit log entries.

But how does it transition from catching up to having joined the cluster. While it is catching up the other 4 machines will be committing a bunch of new writes. So it would seem that it can never really catch.

Does the rejoining node request the cluster to stop processing new writes to let it catch up. And then rejoin by using a consensus algorithm (is that how rejoining is done?). This seems like it would cause a major hiccup delay in processing of writes. What is the idiomatic way of dealing with this?

Comment: Considering the indepth nature of the question, you're likely to get a better response on dba.stackexhange

Comment: Are you using master-master or master-slave configuration ? which cluster technology are you using ? Such information have much influence on what to answer. For MS SQL server db cluster, I recommend refer to this link: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc784005(v=ws.10).aspx , note: it is meant for Win2003 server but the concepts are highly related.

Answer (score 1):

This is not meant as an answer, I do not know. Had trouble getting this readable in a comment.

However. Clustering computer nodes has some of the same problems as does a distributed database.  Data integrity, and who makes "decisions" are two issues in common with databases.

Replicating across geographically disjoint cluster members (like a Solaris geocluster) works somewhat the way a SAN works.  If node A has a dataset (a zfs filesystem for example), any changes originating from node B are stored as deltas, just the way snaphots work.  Getting complete synchronization is not necessarily required because the base of A's dataset plus the deltas== B's dataset.  The are tools to fully sync A and B's datasets at some future time if required.  So if B keeps track of  local data, and then keeps a "snapshot" updated with deltas from A then - everyone is synchronized.  The world is happy.

Now, decisions.  Who does the delta thing?  A or B.? Does A keep track of its own dataset or does it keep track of itself plus the deltas from B?  In a cluster the quorum manager decides.  This is an arbitrarily chosen node that is in charge of decisions.  What in fact may happen is that every "local" node has a unique dataset and then a "snapshot" of deltas from everybody else.  Clusters require an odd number of nodes to function correctly.  You cannot have a quorum when the number of nodes is even. FWIW.

In a geographical cluster, if node A fails in Albuquerque,  node B in New York can almost immediately failover for node A.  That is because B has everything.  The quorum manager decides who fails over for whom in a cluster with lots of members, It can also redistribute application loads from C to D and E if C is swamped (and a bunch of other conditions are true like applications are licensed on C, D, and E)

The point is: 2 nodes do not have identical datasets, but the sums of their collective datasets are as identical as can be had with whatever network latency there is factored into the equation.

Answer (score 0):

This is a very complex topic, and probably can't be answered sensibly in a short post here.

I suggest you read the technical documentation for Cassandra or another mature distributed database.  Cassandra is especially appropriate to your question because it has the concept of tunable consistency -- you can decide what fraction of all databases need to commit in a given transaction.

I think you will find an answer for your question there, plus more questions you haven't though of yet.